# get ajax content inside document ready event

Tags: jquery, ajax

In this example http://jsbin.com/avewul/2/ i use the rcarousel jQuery plugin which slides elements

the idea is to change content of the black title below by the id attribute value of the hovered slide element. that's just work for the first one.

if you remove the the $(document).ready event everything will be ok. but i need it inside the $(document).ready event

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var J_text = $(".change").text();

    $(".slide").hover(function(){
        var J_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".change").text(J_id);
    }, function(){
        $(".change").text(J_text);
    });

});
```

Comment: I didn't get it at all

Comment: The definition of the problem.

Comment: He wants to change the text (rcarousel) when hovering the slide and can't get the text for other than the first slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var J_text = $(".change").text();

    $("body").on('mouseenter', '.slide', function(){
      var J_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".change").text(J_id);
    }).on('mouseleave', '.slide', function(){
      $(".change").text(J_text);
    });
});
```

It delegates the mouseenter and mouseleave event of the slides to the body element. This way the event is also executed for dynamically added elements

Comment: not working too, try to edit it by JSBin and give me a link please

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the carousel plugin dynamically creates and removes slide elements. But newly created elements do not have hover listener bound to them.

You can re-bind the event using rcarousel's [`pageLoaded`](http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/#options) callback:

```
function pageLoaded(event, data) {
    var target = $('.change');
    var text = target.text();

    $(this).hover(
        function() {
            target.text($(this).attr('id'));
        },
        function() {
            target.text(text);
        }
    );

    …
```

Comment: @elkebirmed Use rcarousel's `pageLoaded` event to re-bind the hover event. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$(".slide").on("hover", function() {
        var J_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".change").text(J_id);
    }, function(){
        $(".change").text(J_text);
});
```

Comment: That is what I just tried and it doesn't work - see my comment on @esycat answer

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a callback function in the options (http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/#options) `pageLoaded` to bind your hover event every time the slide moves. It seems that rcarousel unbinds all events on every new slide.

Here is a WORKING solution: http://jsbin.com/upomaf/1

You are using the example file from rcarousel (your last `<sript>` at the bottom of the HTML part). If you take that, you can add the following to the `pageLoaded` function:

```
$(this).hover(
    function() {
        $(".change").text($(".wrapper > div").attr("id"));
    },
    function() {
         $(".change").text(J_text);
    }
);
```